# Webpack modules dependencies like in requirejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs, amd, webpack

I want to migrate from requirejs to webpack and in requirejs config I have:

```
 paths: {
   'jquery.ui.core': 'lib/jquery.ui/jquery.ui.core-1.11.4',
   'jquery.ui.draggable': 'lib/jquery.ui/jquery.ui.draggable-1.11.4',
   'jquery.ui.mouse': 'lib/jquery.ui/jquery.ui.mouse-1.11.4',
   'jquery.ui.widget': 'lib/jquery.ui/jquery.ui.widget-1.11.4',
 ...
 shim: {
   'jquery.ui.mouse': ['jquery.ui.core', 'jquery.ui.widget'],
 ....
```

`jquery.ui.core` and `jquery.ui.widget` are dependencies of `jquery.ui.mouse`. How to make webpack load this modules as dependencies of `jquery.ui.mouse` ?

What webpack's alternative of dependencies in `shim` config property ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to use "imports-loader" for `shim`: https://github.com/webpack/imports-loader

```
loaders: [..., {
   // if use npm module 'jquery-ui' instead of 'lib/...' directory in question
   include: require.resolve('jquery-ui/ui/mouse'), 
   loader: "imports-loader?dep1=jquery.ui.core&dep2=jquery.ui.widget"
}, ...]
```

And for `path` should use `resolve.alias`

```
resolve: {
  ...
  alias: {
    'jquery.ui.core': 'jquery-ui/ui/core',
    'jquery.ui.draggable': 'jquery-ui/ui/draggable',
    'jquery.ui.droppable': 'jquery-ui/ui/droppable',
    'jquery.ui.mouse': 'jquery-ui/ui/mouse',
    'jquery.ui.sortable': 'jquery-ui/ui/sortable',
    'jquery.ui.widget': 'jquery-ui/ui/widget',
    ...
  }
...
}
```